# Google Sheets text wrap no longer expands cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

All of a sudden I seem to be having trouble in my Google Sheets auto extending height of cell with text wrap, for certain cells.

Mac OS: `10.13.6 (17G65)`

Chrome: `Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

I select all cells via `cmd + A` and apply `text-wrap`:

[image]

I scroll to a cell on the bottom I've never formatted previously and type in a long string (Let's say `C1000`):

[image]

The text wraps and expands the cell `C1000` as expected:

[image]

I add text to a cell I had conditionally formatted (conditional format is simply to change it green on a certain value) and changed font of, and add long text, let's say at `C125`:

[image]

The text doesn't wrap in `C125` even though wrapping is applied to it:

[image]

To reveal remaining text in `C125`, I had to manually drag the cell height:

[image]

I thought maybe one of the conditional formats was screwing with it, so I cleared formatting for all cells, and tried entering long text again in `C125`:

[image]

Again, it doesn't wrap. The text continues on in the cell but doesn't push the cell down and expose rest of text:

[image]

Lastly, I thought perhaps that `text-wrap` applies to correctly formatted cells as `plain text`, so I selected all cells again and set the formatting. No luck.

[image]

Can there be a bug with specific cells? Or does copying and pasting text from other sources, such as Mac Notes, cause bugs of this nature?

How can I restore to default such that `text-wrap` works for all cells?